# WCF Transaction Handling from Client/Consumer

Tags: wcf, web-services, translation, wcf-client, webservice-client

I am using WCF to Access My BL and DAL. I want to handle transactions from client not from the BL.

But when I use `TransactionScope` on client side, the transaction does not work correctly. Data is saved if the transaction is aborted or an exception is thrown.

When I use `TransactionScope` in BL it works well.  My problem is that I want to handle transactions from consumer applications not from service. Is there any way to do That?

Any Suggestion? Please Help.

Comment: Take note that in English, only the first words of a sentence, abbreviations and proper nouns are capitalized.

Comment: What binding are you using?What is your service configuration?

Comment: WCF transactions have to be explicitly controlled through a separate protocol, is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730232.aspx) what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope

There can only be two problem

1. The transaction flow is not set for bindings
2. Or using a  binding that does not support distributed transaction